# issues with html and js

Tags: javascript, html, external

This is so bloody frustrating.  I went through W2school tutorials, where bits and pieces are presented to you but it does not answer how to put it all together.  I thought I understood it but when I put it into practice, nothing.  Firebug is telling me that inputEmp() is not defined, but is quite obviously defined in the .js file.  Can someone please tell me what minor detail I left out?  Thanks  First the Html, then the .js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/payroll.css" />

<title>Payroll System</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/payroll.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var emps = new Array();
</script>   
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Jackson Payroll System</h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="inputEmp()">
    Click here to enter employees
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// payroll.js
function inputEmp() {
    var inName = "";
    var loopCt = 0
    var tArray = new Array();

    while (inName != "-1}
    {
        prompt inName = prompt("Please enter your name (enter -1 to finish)",
                               "Employee Name");
    if (inName == "-1")  { break; }
    if (inName==null || inName=="")
    {
        alert("Blank names are not allowed.  To exit enter '-1'.");
    } 
    else
        tArray[loopCt++] = inName;
    {

    }
    return tArray;
}
```

Comment: Put the `<script>` tags referencing `payroll.js` at the end of the `body`

Comment: if you're still stuck, i'd try defining 'inputEmp' with js in the same html file and make sure it works before moving it to a separate file.

Comment: You forgot to close the quotes in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you forgot to close the brace { of while loop before return statement. and the quotes is not closed in condition.

Try this

```
    function inputEmp() {
    var inName = "";
    var loopCt = 0
    var tArray = new Array();

    while (inName != "-1"} {
        prompt inName = prompt("Please enter your name (enter -1 to finish)","Employee Name");
    if (inName == "-1")  { break; }
    if (inName==null || inName=="")
        {
        alert("Blank names are not allowed.  To exit enter '-1'.");
        } 
    else
        tArray[loopCt++] = inName;
    {

    }
    }
    return tArray;
    }
```

Comment: The main issue is at ```while (inName != "-1} {```, the quote is unclosed.

Comment: Also forgot to end the quote in the while condition.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

prompt inName = prompt("Please enter your name (enter -1 to finish)

Comment: ignore last one, i figured it out

Comment: May I ask a follow up ?  How can I view the array elements.  Supposedly I can do it with firebug, but I cannot find where.

Comment: Sorry, I am a chrome guy.. You might be able to type in the name of array in JS Console like in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of problem in your code:

`var loopCt = 0` should look like this `var loopCt = 0;`

`while (inName != "-1}` should look like this `while (inName != "-1)`

`prompt inName = prompt...` should look like this `inName = prompt...`

There is an empty `{ }` under the else statement

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxEwN/) that shows you the corrected code.